# mantener apagado mysql-server linux

Tags: mysql, linux

### Contexto.

Tengo instalado `mysql-server` en mi computadora linux. Utilizo bastante mysql pero también hay días o ratos en los que no, y en esos momentos en el que no utilizo `mysql-server` quisiera que permaneciera apagado porque me parece que está gastando recursos de mi computador innecesariamente.

### Problema.

Si bien ejecutando `sudo service mysql stop` puedo detener el servidor de mysql, cuando apago y vuelvo a prender el computador corro `sudo service mysql status` y me sale que está activo.

### Conclusión.

Necesito saber cómo hacer para que el estado de apagado permanezca activo independientemente de si apago o no el pc.

### Entorno.

- PC: Linux Mint 20.2
- `mysql --version`: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Algunos comandos útiles:

```
# Desactiva para que no cargue al encender el equipo
sudo systemctl disable mysql

# Detener servicio
sudo systemctl stop mysql

# Iniciar servicio
sudo systemctl start mysql

# Volver a activar para cargar al encender
sudo systemctl enable mysql
```